# Interpretation of Logistic Regression Model Using Glmnet()

Tags: r, logistic

In the Linear Regression Model, say I want to see the correlation between car_speed and the number of accidents.

That is easy for me to understand. Now for the logic regression model, my response variable is either 0 or 1.

**How do I understand this model?**

```
> # Prep Training and Test data.
> trainDataIndex <- sample(1:nrow(df), 0.7*nrow(df))  # 70% training 
  data
> trainData <- df[trainDataIndex, ]
> testData <- df[-trainDataIndex, ]
> set.seed(100)
> trainData <- 
+   trainData %>%
+   dplyr::mutate(CUST_REGION_DESCR = 
+                   forcats::fct_relabel(CUST_REGION_DESCR, ~ trimws(.x)))
> testData <- 
+   testData %>%
+   dplyr::mutate(CUST_REGION_DESCR = 
+                   forcats::fct_relabel(CUST_REGION_DESCR, ~ trimws(.x)))
> str(trainData)
'data.frame':   693843 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cust_prog_level  : Factor w/ 14 levels "B","C","D","E",..: 9 7 10 9 10 9 10 5 10 5 ...
 $ CUST_REGION_DESCR: Factor w/ 8 levels "CORPORATE REGION",..: 2 6 7 6 8 8 4 7 7 6 ...
 $ Sales            : num  92.7 2356 39 239.6 26 ...
 $ New_Product_Type : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> str(testData)
'data.frame':   297362 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cust_prog_level  : Factor w/ 14 levels "B","C","D","E",..: 9 5 9 9 9 9 3 3 5 3 ...
 $ CUST_REGION_DESCR: Factor w/ 8 levels "CORPORATE REGION",..: 3 3 6 6 7 6 7 2 2 4 ...
 $ Sales            : num  150.2 68.5 68.1 72.1 60.1 ...
 $ New_Product_Type : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> x = model.matrix(New_Product_Type ~.,data=trainData)

> cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y=as.factor(trainData$New_Product_Type), alpha=1, family="binomial",type.measure = "mse")

> lambda_1se <- cvfit$lambda.1se

> coef(cvfit,s=lambda_1se)
23 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                                                1
(Intercept)                            0.02946581
(Intercept)                            .         
cust_prog_levelC                       0.14012975
cust_prog_levelD                       .         
cust_prog_levelE                       0.13339906
cust_prog_levelG                      -0.05325043
cust_prog_levelI                       0.21440592
cust_prog_levelL                       0.26273503
cust_prog_levelM                       .         
cust_prog_levelN                       0.26620261
cust_prog_levelP                      -0.05166799
cust_prog_levelR                      -0.33054803
cust_prog_levelS                       .         
cust_prog_levelX                       0.57508875
cust_prog_levelZ                       1.20748454
CUST_REGION_DESCRMOUNTAIN WEST REGION -0.20993854
CUST_REGION_DESCRNORTH CENTRAL REGION -0.04035331
CUST_REGION_DESCRNORTH EAST REGION     0.01082858
CUST_REGION_DESCROHIO VALLEY REGION    0.03077584
CUST_REGION_DESCRSOUTH CENTRAL REGION  .         
CUST_REGION_DESCRSOUTH EAST REGION     0.10606213
CUST_REGION_DESCRWESTERN REGION       -0.17587036
Sales                                 -0.01223843

> #get test data
> x_test <- model.matrix(New_Product_Type~.,data = testData)
> #predict New_Product_Type, type=”New_Product_Type”
> lasso_prob <- predict(cvfit,newx = x_test,s=lambda_1se,type="response")

> #translate probabilities to predictions
> lasso_predict <- rep("0",nrow(testData))
> lasso_predict[lasso_prob>.5] <- "1"
> #confusion matrix


> table(pred=lasso_predict,true=testData$New_Product_Type)
    true
pred      0      1
   0 207345  60553
   1   9004  20460
> 
> #accuracy
> mean(lasso_predict==testData$New_Product_Type)
[1] 0.7660865
```

Specifically, 0 relates to "Nobody buys this product/They buy others" and "1" relates to "They buy the House-Product". There're three predictors for this mode.

**How can I interpret the result summary(cvfit)?**

The mean() now returns " 0.7660865". **What does it imply?**

Comment: @Matthew Drury I made a new post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interpret the coefficient estimates from glmnet the same way you would interpret them as if you ran a regular GLM logistic regression.  There are plenty of resources on this site and online for interpreting logistic regression coefficients.  The coefficients with . next to them were set to 0 via the lasso penalty (it's lasso because you set alpha = 1).

Your last statement is computing the number of times the prediction equals the label, i.e. the model accuracy, which you can get from the table above it:

```
(207345+20460)/(207345+20460+60553+9004)=0.7660865
```

Comment: Can you please pin out the resource where I can find the interpretation of glmnet() coefficients?

Comment: As in the answer, since you are running a regularized (lasso) logistic regression, you interpret the coefficients as you would in a normal logistic regression setting.  Google "interpreting logistic regression coefficients".

Comment: I am sorry I have to come back here to ask another question. Can you please explain to me again what model accuracy means. Your comment said the number of times the prediction equals the label. So I would say: the model predicts that out of 100 times trials, about 77 of them say there are 207345 and 20460?

Comment: Take a look here for all the metrics you can calculate from a confusion matrix (with accuracy being one of them): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix